# Firefox crashes Gnome Session

Tags: release-loki, greeter, desktop, gnome

Firefox crashes when unlocking a locked session. This in itself is a Firefox issue.

But the problem is that this crash cascades and crashes a gnome session, returning me to the login screen.

I can log back in perfectly well, but the session is all new.
This does not happen on every unlock, usually you have to wait a few minutes to unlock for it to crash.

That makes this bug particularly annoying because it's so difficult to reproduce, and to me suggests race conditions.

Interestingly, when I run Firefox from terminal it crashes, prints errors, but does not crash the session.

Usually, I am able to resolve issues by myself, but in this instance I've hit a wall. I am not familiar with how exactly the GUI system works and would therefore appreciate any help.

This system worked for years without any significant problems, but after the latest Firefox update this issue appeared.

**System information:**

```
lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: elementary
Description:    elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki
Release:    0.4.1
Codename:   loki
```

```
uname -a

Linux xxx-pc 4.4.0-164-generic #192-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 13 12:02:50 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
gnome-shell --version 

GNOME Shell 3.18.5
```

**~/.Xauthority** and **~/.ICEauthority** are owned by my user and **~/.xsession-errors** is completely empty.

**Firefox error messages (terminal output):**

```
(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:13869): dconf-WARNING **: Unable to open /var/lib/snapd/desktop/dconf/profile/user: Permission denied
[Parent 13737, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: Broken pipe: file /build/firefox-EymEXX/firefox-69.0.1+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 728
[Parent 13737, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: Broken pipe: file /build/firefox-EymEXX/firefox-69.0.1+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 728
[Parent 13737, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: Broken pipe: file /build/firefox-EymEXX/firefox-69.0.1+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 728
[Parent 13737, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: Broken pipe: file /build/firefox-EymEXX/firefox-69.0.1+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 728

(/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:13794): dconf-WARNING **: Unable to open /var/lib/snapd/desktop/dconf/profile/user: Permission denied
[GFX1-]: Killing GPU process due to IPC reply timeout
[GFX1-]: Receive IPC close with reason=AbnormalShutdown
[GFX1-]: Receive IPC close with reason=AbnormalShutdown
[GFX1-]: Receive IPC close with reason=AbnormalShutdown

###!!! [Parent][RunMessage] Error: Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x2000F,name=PAPZInputBridge::Msg_UpdateWheelTransaction) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel::SendAndWait] Error: (msgtype=0x20010,name=PAPZInputBridge::Msg_ProcessUnhandledEvent) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Child][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x330032,name=PCompositorBridge::Msg_NotifyRegionInvalidated) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Child][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x590001,name=PLayerTransaction::Msg_Update) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Child][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x590016,name=PLayerTransaction::Msg_ScheduleComposite) Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][RunMessage] Error: Channel error: cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][RunMessage] Error: Channel error: cannot send/recv

[GFX1-]: Receive IPC close with reason=AbnormalShutdown

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x4D001A,name=PGPU::Msg_ShutdownVR) Channel error: cannot send/recv

Terminated
```

**Relevant syslog section:**

https://pastebin.com/BdSR5tXT

**lightdm.log:**

```
[+6981.87s] DEBUG: Greeter start authentication for xxx
[+6981.87s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Failed to work out session ID to mark
[+6981.87s] DEBUG: Session pid=18581: Started with service 'lightdm', username 'xxx'
[+6981.88s] DEBUG: Session pid=18581: Got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+6981.88s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
[+6993.38s] DEBUG: Continue authentication
[+6993.41s] DEBUG: Session pid=18581: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+6993.41s] DEBUG: Authenticate result for user xxx: Success
[+6993.41s] DEBUG: User xxx authorized
[+6993.78s] DEBUG: Greeter requests session pantheon
[+6993.78s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Returning to existing user session xxx
[+6993.78s] DEBUG: Unlocking login1 session c12
[+6993.79s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+6995.06s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping greeter
[+6995.06s] DEBUG: Session pid=18518: Sending SIGTERM
[+6995.06s] DEBUG: Activating login1 session c12
[+6995.07s] DEBUG: Session pid=18581: Exited with return value 0
[+6995.07s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
[+6995.07s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to c12
[+6995.07s] DEBUG: Session c12 is already active
[+6995.08s] DEBUG: Session pid=18518: Exited with return value 0
[+6995.08s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
[+6995.08s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping display server, no sessions require it
[+6995.08s] DEBUG: Sending signal 15 to process 18510
[+6995.10s] DEBUG: Process 18510 exited with return value 0
[+6995.10s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: X server stopped
[+6995.10s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 8
[+6995.10s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-1: Removing X server authority /var/run/lightdm/root/:1
[+6995.10s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server stopped
[+6995.79s] DEBUG: Session pid=8453: Exited with return value 0
[+6995.79s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
[+6995.79s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping display server, no sessions require it
[+6995.79s] DEBUG: Sending signal 15 to process 8388
[+6996.22s] DEBUG: Process 8388 exited with return value 0
[+6996.22s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: X server stopped
[+6996.22s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 7
[+6996.22s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Removing X server authority /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+6996.22s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server stopped
[+6996.22s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Active display server stopped, starting greeter
[+6996.22s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating greeter session
[+6996.22s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating display server of type x
[+6996.22s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
[+6996.22s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Starting local X display on VT 7
[+6996.22s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/x-0.log
[+6996.22s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Writing X server authority to /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+6996.22s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Launching X Server
[+6996.22s] DEBUG: Launching process 18700: /usr/bin/X -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten tcp vt7 -novtswitch
[+6996.22s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Waiting for ready signal from X server :0
[+6996.74s] DEBUG: Got signal 10 from process 18700
[+6996.74s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Got signal from X server :0
[+6996.74s] DEBUG: DisplayServer x-0: Connecting to XServer :0
[+6996.75s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server ready, starting session authentication
[+6996.75s] DEBUG: Session pid=18710: Started with service 'lightdm-greeter', username 'lightdm'
[+6996.76s] DEBUG: Session pid=18710: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+6996.76s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session authenticated, running command
[+6996.76s] DEBUG: Session pid=18710: Running command /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session /usr/sbin/pantheon-greeter
[+6996.76s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm-data/lightdm
[+6996.76s] DEBUG: Session pid=18710: Logging to /var/log/lightdm/seat0-greeter.log
[+6996.79s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+6996.79s] DEBUG: Activating login1 session c16
[+6996.79s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to c16
[+6996.79s] DEBUG: Session c16 is already active
[+6997.02s] DEBUG: Greeter connected version=1.18.3 resettable=false
[+6999.17s] DEBUG: Greeter start authentication for xxx
[+6999.17s] DEBUG: Session pid=18770: Started with service 'lightdm', username 'xxx'
[+6999.18s] DEBUG: Session pid=18770: Got 1 message(s) from PAM
[+6999.18s] DEBUG: Prompt greeter with 1 message(s)
[+7001.68s] DEBUG: Continue authentication
[+7001.70s] DEBUG: Session pid=18770: Authentication complete with return value 0: Success
[+7001.70s] DEBUG: Authenticate result for user xxx: Success
[+7001.70s] DEBUG: User xxx authorized
[+7002.04s] DEBUG: Greeter requests session pantheon
[+7002.04s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping greeter; display server will be re-used for user session
[+7002.04s] DEBUG: Session pid=18710: Sending SIGTERM
[+7002.05s] DEBUG: Session pid=18710: Exited with return value 0
[+7002.05s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Session stopped
[+7002.05s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Greeter stopped, running session
[+7002.05s] DEBUG: Registering session with bus path /org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session3
[+7002.05s] DEBUG: Session pid=18770: Running command /usr/sbin/lightdm-session gnome-session --session=pantheon
[+7002.05s] DEBUG: Creating shared data directory /var/lib/lightdm-data/xxx
[+7002.05s] DEBUG: Session pid=18770: Logging to .xsession-errors
[+7002.09s] DEBUG: Activating VT 7
[+7002.09s] DEBUG: Activating login1 session c17
[+7002.09s] DEBUG: Seat seat0 changes active session to c17
[+7002.09s] DEBUG: Session c17 is already active
```

**lightdm/seat0-greeter.log:**

```
(gnome-settings-daemon:11593): GLib-CRITICAL **: Source ID 320 was not found when attempting to remove it
** Message: LightDMGateway.vala:84: Connecting to LightDM...
** Message: LightDMGateway.vala:93: Successfully connected to LightDM.
** Message: IndicatorBar.vala:53: Loading indicators...
** Message: IndicatorBar.vala:63: Loading indicator bluetooth...
** Message: IndicatorBar.vala:63: Loading indicator session...

(pantheon-greeter:14569): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(pantheon-greeter:14569): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
** Message: IndicatorBar.vala:63: Loading indicator power...

(pantheon-greeter:14569): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_box_pack: assertion '_gtk_widget_get_parent (child) == NULL' failed
** Message: IndicatorBar.vala:63: Loading indicator network...

** (pantheon-greeter:14569): CRITICAL **: g_ptr_array_get_length: assertion 'self != NULL' failed

(pantheon-greeter:14569): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_ptr_array_foreach: assertion 'array' failed

(pantheon-greeter:14569): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_no_show_all: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(pantheon-greeter:14569): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(pantheon-greeter:14569): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_ptr_array_foreach: assertion 'array' failed

(pantheon-greeter:14569): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(pantheon-greeter:14569): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(pantheon-greeter:14569): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(pantheon-greeter:14569): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

** (pantheon-greeter:14569): WARNING **: Wallpaper.vala:55: Key file does not have key 'default-wallpaper' in group 'greeter'

** (pantheon-greeter:14569): WARNING **: PantheonGreeter.vala:162: Key file does not have key 'activate-numlock' in group 'greeter'
** Message: EntryList.vala:39: Resorting indicators...
** Message: LightDMGateway.vala:105: Starting authentication...
** Message: LightDMGateway.vala:150: LightDM prompt: 'Password: ' (LIGHTDM_PROMPT_TYPE_SECRET)

** (gnome-settings-daemon:14609): WARNING **: Unable to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such method 'RegisterClient'

(gnome-settings-daemon:14609): updates-plugin-WARNING **: failed to get upgrades: Spawn of helper '/usr/share/PackageKit/helpers/aptcc/get-distro-upgrade.py' failed: failed to spawn /usr/share/PackageKit/helpers/aptcc/get-distro-upgrade.py: Failed to execute child process "/usr/share/PackageKit/helpers/aptcc/get-distro-upgrade.py" (No such file or directory)
** Message: PantheonGreeter.vala:220: restore user timeout: 600
** Message: LightDMGateway.vala:262: Starting session pantheon

** (gnome-settings-daemon:14609): WARNING **: Name taken or bus went away - shutting down

(pantheon-greeter:14569): Gdk-WARNING **: pantheon-greeter: Fatal IO error 0 (Success) on X server :1.


(gnome-settings-daemon:14609): Gdk-WARNING **: gnome-settings-daemon: Fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server :1.

** Message: LightDMGateway.vala:84: Connecting to LightDM...
** Message: LightDMGateway.vala:93: Successfully connected to LightDM.
** Message: IndicatorBar.vala:53: Loading indicators...
** Message: IndicatorBar.vala:63: Loading indicator bluetooth...
** Message: IndicatorBar.vala:63: Loading indicator session...

(pantheon-greeter:18536): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(pantheon-greeter:18536): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed
** Message: IndicatorBar.vala:63: Loading indicator power...

(pantheon-greeter:18536): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_box_pack: assertion '_gtk_widget_get_parent (child) == NULL' failed
** Message: IndicatorBar.vala:63: Loading indicator network...

** (pantheon-greeter:18536): CRITICAL **: g_ptr_array_get_length: assertion 'self != NULL' failed

(pantheon-greeter:18536): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_ptr_array_foreach: assertion 'array' failed

(pantheon-greeter:18536): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_no_show_all: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(pantheon-greeter:18536): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_set_visible: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

(pantheon-greeter:18536): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_ptr_array_foreach: assertion 'array' failed

(pantheon-greeter:18536): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(pantheon-greeter:18536): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

(pantheon-greeter:18536): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(pantheon-greeter:18536): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_object: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

** (pantheon-greeter:18536): WARNING **: Wallpaper.vala:55: Key file does not have key 'default-wallpaper' in group 'greeter'

** (pantheon-greeter:18536): WARNING **: PantheonGreeter.vala:162: Key file does not have key 'activate-numlock' in group 'greeter'
** Message: EntryList.vala:39: Resorting indicators...
** Message: LightDMGateway.vala:105: Starting authentication...
** Message: LightDMGateway.vala:150: LightDM prompt: 'Password: ' (LIGHTDM_PROMPT_TYPE_SECRET)
** Message: Wallpaper.vala:130: Cancelled to load '/usr/share/backgrounds/elementaryos-default'

** (gnome-settings-daemon:18574): WARNING **: Unable to register client: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such method 'RegisterClient'

(gnome-settings-daemon:18574): updates-plugin-WARNING **: failed to get upgrades: Spawn of helper '/usr/share/PackageKit/helpers/aptcc/get-distro-upgrade.py' failed: failed to spawn /usr/share/PackageKit/helpers/aptcc/get-distro-upgrade.py: Failed to execute child process "/usr/share/PackageKit/helpers/aptcc/get-distro-upgrade.py" (No such file or directory)
** Message: PantheonGreeter.vala:220: restore user timeout: 600
** Message: LightDMGateway.vala:262: Starting session pantheon

** (gnome-settings-daemon:18574): WARNING **: Name taken or bus went away - shutting down

(pantheon-greeter:18536): Gdk-WARNING **: pantheon-greeter: Fatal IO error 0 (Success) on X server :1.
```

**lightdm/x-0.log:**

```
X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-128-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux xxx-pc 4.4.0-164-generic #192-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 13 12:02:50 UTC 2019 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-164-generic root=UUID=2288b46a-c118-4015-b0ff-5a5c598e8eb2 ro net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 quiet splash radeon.dpm=1 vt.handoff=7
Build Date: 10 August 2018  09:33:05AM
xorg-server 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.8 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Sep 29 01:58:18 2019
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(II) [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
The XKEYBOARD keymap compiler (xkbcomp) reports:
> Warning:          Type "ONE_LEVEL" has 1 levels, but <RALT> has 2 symbols
>                   Ignoring extra symbols
Errors from xkbcomp are not fatal to the X server
(II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
(II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
(II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
(II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

**lightdm/x-1.log:**

```
X.Org X Server 1.18.4
Release Date: 2016-07-19
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-128-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux xxx-pc 4.4.0-164-generic #192-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 13 12:02:50 UTC 2019 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-164-generic root=UUID=2288b46a-c118-4015-b0ff-5a5c598e8eb2 ro net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0 quiet splash radeon.dpm=1 vt.handoff=7
Build Date: 10 August 2018  09:33:05AM
xorg-server 2:1.18.4-0ubuntu0.8 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.33.6
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.1.log", Time: Sun Sep 29 13:40:32 2019
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
Xorg: ../../dix/privates.c:385: dixRegisterPrivateKey: Assertion `!global_keys[type].created' failed.
```

**Xorg.1.log:**

https://pastebin.com/gbCncjDq

Comment: You can report this issue to GNOME developers @ https://gitlab.gnome.org/groups/GNOME/-/issues

Comment: I did, but they said that my version (the one shipped whit Elementary) is outdated and they will not waste time with it.

Comment: Have you tried installing newest version of Firefox instead of one that ships with eOS?

Comment: I didn't but the version in the repo is the newest. Even if it wasn't, a buggy program should never be able to crash a desktop environment running as a non privileged user.